# Is it possible to change the 'Check Email' shortcut in Dash?

Tags: unity, 11.04, mail, unity-dash

In Unity Dash, the 'Browse the Web' shortcut launches the browser selected by the user in 'Preferred Applications'.

But the 'Check Email' shortcut always launches Evolution, even if another email application is selected in 'Preferred Applications'.

Is there a way to change this behavior?

Comment: It sound more like a bug than a forced choice. Please file a bug, https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+filebug

Comment: This is exactly why this site shouldn't be used for pre-releases. Most of the questions will be irrelevant after a short time, but they will stay here, taking up time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bug has been fixed in a recent Natty update, the shortcut now use the correct application to check mail.

Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't change when you change `Preferred Applications` it's bug.

Please report this bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity

Yours,

Daniel

Comment: Ok, this seems to be a known bug: [https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/754095]. I'd still be happy to know if there is any workaround that currently work, as I have to setup a computer for an inexperienced person, and this evolution shortcut will be confusing (since she will use webmail).

Comment: It looks like only `thunderbird` cannot be added as favorite. Try another mailing program or wait until the bug gets fixed :) Maybe there's a workaround, but I don't know one yet.

Comment: It's not only thundebird, as this does not work with GMail, nor Claws. I think the sortcut is fixed to evolution...

Comment: strange thing is it works in unity-2d

Answer (score 0):

You could always remove Evolution from **Synaptic Package Manager** and install Thunderbird, but install it via Ubuntu Tweak.  I recommend that way because when I compiled Thunderbird from .tar.bz2 and installed it correctly the Thunderbird icon would not appear in the dash even after I restarted the PC to make sure.

***Warning***

When you go to Synaptic Package Manager, **do not** remove **Evolution Data Server Common** as that will uninstall the Ubuntu Desktop and a few other things that are essential.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible, however I believe the unexpected behavior you are seeing is due to this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/708479